# Anroid JetPack Compose Unable to copy/paste a comma delimetted string to Windows 10 clipboard

Tags: android, windows, clipboard

My Android phone is paired to my Windows 11 PC. In it's Link to Windows is "sees" my desktop and states it is connected. In my Windows 11 PC settings - clipboard is set to sync and under Bluetooth is "sees" my phone. In my sample you will notice that I send an AnnotatedString. I sense that is my problem

```
 val clipboardManager = LocalClipboardManager.current
 val  output = "Hello World"
 clipboardManager.setText(AnnotatedString(output.toString()))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this fun:

```
import android.content.ClipData
import android.content.ClipboardManager
import android.content.Context
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat


fun copyToClipboard(context: Context, text: String) {
    val clipboard = ContextCompat.getSystemService(context, ClipboardManager::class.java)
    clipboard?.setPrimaryClip(ClipData.newPlainText("", text))
}
```

Like that

```
val context = LocalContext.current
copyToClipboard(context = context, text = "Text to copy")
```

Comment: it.setPrimaryClip does not compile. it has setText but does not accept (ClipData.newPlainText("", text))

Comment: I have added implementations in my answer, please recheck if you are using them. I think you are using wrong ClipboardManager.

Comment: The clipboard manager that I am using  is Android JetPack Compose.... import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalClipboardManager

Comment: Glad for you! Try another one, which is android.content.ClipboardManager

Comment: I changed my imports to agree with your sample. My code is contained within a @Composable function. I get two errors, "this' is not defined and my version of 'context' does not contain 'copyToClipboard'... Thanks for your help

Comment: The function "fun Context.copyToClipboard" should not be in Composable scope, place it in MainActivity, for example.

Comment: I placed the code in non Composable class. The statement - val context = LocalContext.current, causes a compiler error, The "current" element is the problem. Error message - Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function

Comment: Function copyToClipboard should be non composable and "val context = LocalContext.current
context.copyToClipboard(text = "Text to copy")" - should be used inside a composable

Comment: I moved the code to a Composable function. I created the appropriate import. However, 'context' does not contain  a copyToClipboard(..) method.

Comment: Check the definition of the non-composable fun "fun Context.copyToClipboard(text: String)" and also imports for it "import android.content.ClipData
import android.content.ClipboardManager
import android.content.Context
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat"

Comment: My prior post was not complete. The code in the non-composable function compiles with no problem! The code in the composable function is where the problem exists, Jetpack Compose's 'context' does not have:  copyToClipboard

Comment: Check if this func started with Context. (should be like fun Context.copyToClipboard(text: String) and not private)

Comment: I changed my function as follows:  Context.copyToClipboard(text = "Text to copy") The compiler fails. It's OK with 'Contex', but does not like - copyToClipboard...

Comment: I also created a non Composable function which made the same call and get the same compiler error...

Comment: Have you added the rest of the function? {...}?

Comment: This is the call from my non-Composable function that fails:     Context.copyToClipboard(text = "Text to copy")

Comment: Your composable call should be "val context = LocalContext.current
context.copyToClipboard(text = "Text to copy")"

Comment: That code does not compile. "context"  does not contain "copyToClipboard" .

Comment: I have changed the function in my answer. Please, try again with the new variant

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Composable
fun PasteToWindows(context:Context) {
    val message = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    message.value = "Hello World Again & Again and"
    // Initializing the ClipboardManager and Clip data
    val clipboardManager =
        context.getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
    // clip data is initialized with the text variable declared above
    var clipData: ClipData = ClipData.newPlainText("text", message.value)
    clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData)
}
```

To copy from Windows clipboard, Add the "Swift Key"
app to your Android phone. It enhances the Keypad with a clipboard property